# Course attribute/metadata API?

Tags: desire2learn

We'd like to stash extra "metadata" about an org unit somewhere - for example a simple key/value pair - so that we can go back and read/use it at a later date. Is there a recommended way that we could do this? We've thought of - for example - creating a new topic in the org unit and "hiding" the values in the HTML of the topic, but then instructors could theoretically see/be confused by it. Are there any other ways to repurpose an existing object to support this goal?

Thank you,
-George

Answer (score 1):

Currently, the Valence Learning Framework API does not expose functionality like this. You are not the first person to inquire about this kind of functionality, and so I would encourage you to present/log this idea with Desire2Learn's [Product Idea Exchange](https://community.desire2learn.com/announcing-the-product-idea-exchange/) -- a moderated/voted list that can act (in part) as an input from clients to D2L to set future direction for product development.